# Incorrectly sent ERC20 (C20) token to a contract address

Tags: erc-20, transfer

I mistakenly sent ERC20 (C20) tokens to a C20 contract address. There are two transaction hashes on the block. One shows that the C20 was sent (to a C20 contract wallet address) and is successful (0xf5e2374eee433fb7a8a6e3c32161ef6c15ed7ce99e6561be394fd7e95395f4c3), then one right after that has a "fail/reverted" status (0x63dd592448262f2823ac810a4fb10e99a8d14d53e747e040bcf59f19633fd1d0).

I'm hoping that the coins get "reverted" back to the sending address (my wallet), but the first transaction being "successful" and showing that the coins were successfully sent to a wallet address other than my own, has me concerned. Anyone ever heard of a scenario like this, and know how it plays out? Any suggestions on what to do? I sent a support email on etherscan so far. TIA

Comment: In the first transaction, your tokens were sent to `0x38B7E507C5792A06A94DC103426160aB46c0888D`, which is not a contract address. Do you have the private key for this address?

Comment: It's not my address. I mistakenly tried to "add custom token" on my ether wallet and put the contract id into the add custom token box, and put the decimals in the box below. it then just went to that address... I just figured it was their contract address because of how i entered the contract id into mew. On the block chain, it shows it was sent to "Crypto 20" also

Comment: I'm afraid your tokens are lost if this is not your address. The address does not appear to be active, since there's no other transactions on it.

Comment: It has the same contract ID as the other transaction, and the "to address" is labeled as "Crypto 20." I emailed them to inquire about it. I'm hoping that they have access to this wallet as it is somehow tied to the contract ID that i input. We will see though. Thanks for the feedback!